# return number of records above 0 and equal or less than 18 - excell

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to count the number of records where the age is between 0 and 18 inclusive.

Can anyone help?

```
=count.if('Controlo'!D3:D700;"<0:>=18")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CountIfs`. For e.g.

`=COUNTIFS(A1:A6,">=0",A1:A6,"<=18")`

Comment: thanks but i get error, the only way it dont gives me error is =COUNTIFS('Controlo Atendimentos'!D5:D502;"<=30")*COUNTIFS('Controlo Atendimentos'!D5:D502;">=39") but it gives me 34 instead of 14.  thanks

Comment: It works for me even if I reference a sheet. What is the error? Can you show sample data

Comment: The OP has his "List Separator" as a `;` in his Language settings.  So you should give and example of your answer using `;` instead of `,`

Answer (score 0):

Or use *SUMPRODUCT()*

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Controlo!D3:D700>=0)*(Controlo!D3:D700<=18))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`COUNTIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53c4dc8e-0e5b-4e32-93df-9ca5e7da89ed) will do the trick for you, it takes in multiple arguments to determine what to count.

You have already defined both your arguments to be ">0" (greater than 0 exclusive) and "<=18" (less than 18 inclusive).  So we put those into the formula:

```
=COUNTIFS('Controlo'!D3:D700;">0";'Controlo'!D3:D700;"<=18")
                             ^^^^ first criteria      ^^^^^ second criteria
```

For those that use a `,` to separate paramters in Excel you can just replace the semi-colons with commas:

```
=COUNTIFS('Controlo'!D3:D700,">0",'Controlo'!D3:D700,"<=18")
```